# more succinct ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there are more succinct or Rubyesque way of writing this:

```
if ( variable =~ /regex1/ || variable =~ /regex2/ || variable =~ /regex3/ ... )
end
```

Namely, I'm hoping for something shorter, like:

```
if ( variable =~ /regex1/,/regex2/,/regex3/ )
```

which I realize is not valid Ruby code, but figuring someone may know a more clever trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about...

```
if ( variable =~ /regex1|regex2|regex3/ )
end
```

Answer (score 6):

```
[/regex1/,/regex2/,/regex3/].any?{|r| r =~ variable}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a switch, or merge the expressions (if that's possible), or use a find:

```
if ([/regex1/, /regex2/].find {|r| v =~ r}) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
variable =~ Regexp.union(/regex1/, /regex2/, /regex3/)
```

This is assuming you can't use VoteyDisciple's which would make the most sense where it's possible.